# I can't access sculpt vertex paint in 2.90 alpha

Tags: texturing

I don't know, I downloaded it 3 times, and the sculpt vertex brush is just not there. I see all of the other sculpt mode brushes, but sculpt vertex paint is nowhere to be found.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Open [user preferences](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/introduction.html#introduction)
- Under [*interface*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/interface.html#interface) enable *Develeper
  Extras*
  [image]
- After enabling the developer extras, *Experimental* will appear in
  the menu enabling the experimental features making the options below
  available (as of f319eec88186)
  [image]